# LPT1 to USB converter fast speed

Tags: usb, parallel, converter

I have a DOS Based "black box" which prints out to the parallel port,
the need is to capture these data for later analysis.

I saw some project based on FT245R, do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a microcontroller to interpret the data and send it over serial (or RS232->USB link if you need USB) to the other system. Should be a pretty simple build.